# converting BYTE array to LPCWSTR C++

Tags: c++

i'm writing implementation of some functions. Now I'm on converting BYTE array to LPCWSTR. I created this code.

```
LPCWSTR byte2wch(BYTE* data, int size)
{
    wchar_t* datas = (wchar_t*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, sizeof(wchar_t) * (size + 1));
    LPCWSTR temp = (reinterpret_cast<wchar_t const*>(data));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        datas[i] = temp[i];
    }
    datas[sizeof(wchar_t) * (size + 1)] = 0;
    LPCWSTR tempo = datas;
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&datas);
    return tempo;
}
```

But this function returns unicode string with some unicode characters in the end. I don't why, I've set a `NULL`pointer in the end of `LPCWSTR`

Comment: What about [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function?

Comment: Remove the call to `HeapFree()` - you still need to use the string you just created!

Comment: @NutCracker better use own implementations.

Comment: @AdrianMole it clearing datas, nit tempo

Comment: i wrongly setting NULL terminated string...

Comment: Are you aware of encoding? Your conversion may work for plain ASCII exclusively/reliable. What does `BYTE *data` contain (semantically)?

Comment: some king of string like this: jkfdajfajsd

Comment: The `HeapFree()` looks highly suspicious. 1. You may not free a pointer to memory which shall be used afterwards! (That's undefined behavior.) 2. Correct it would be `HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (LPVOID)datas);` (without taking address of `datas`), wouldn't it? I'm not sure what the `HeapFree()` does at all in your case - hardly something good. So, I'm with @AdrianMole: Remove this line to sleep better...

Comment: FYI: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) ;-)

Comment: The line `LPCWSTR tempo = datas;` simply copies the pointer. Then, when you free one, you are also freeing the other.

Comment: @Scheff will it cause memory leak? because I need to free memory...

Comment: how can I save LPCWSTR and free memory?

Comment: It will cause a memory leak if you don't free it after you don't need it anymore. But, deleting it when it's still in use is not the solution. If you return a pointer but free the memory it points to - you have a dangling pointer - one of the most accidents in C/C++. Contents might still be there or not or partly destroyed or...

Comment: You cannot. `LPCWSTR` is just a pointer. You can allocate memory and store the address of it in `LPCWSTR` but this is what you already have.

Comment: You could consider to work with `std::` containers instead. They provide their own (dynamic) memory management and help to prevent memory leaks in this and other situations by built-in features. Have a look on `std::string`/`std::wstring` or `std::vector`.

Comment: I can't use string library... CRT...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208176/discussion-between-korozya-and-scheff).

Comment: C++ without std library? Seriously?

Comment: yes. I need as smaller as possible size

Comment: Let me be blunt, here: You aren't going to write a program that doesn't use the CRT for quite a while. This task is *very* involved, requiring intimate familiarity with the target platform and programming language. And here you are, struggling with the fundamentals of programming (like pointers). Your options are to either drop the idea that you can write a program without using the programming language's support libraries, or invest a *significant* amount of time to familiarize yourself with the programming language.